# preg_match between textarea in string in php

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

```
preg_match("/ [>](.*)[<] /", '<textarea width="500" >web scripting language of choice.</textarea>',$matches);
print_r ($matches);
```

i want to return just "web scripting language of choice." form this string.
please help me.
to arrive this 
PHP

Comment: Use a DOM parser instead of a regex.

Comment: remove spaces or add a x after your `/` delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a DOM parser

HTML is not a regular language and cannot be correctly parsed using a regular expression. Use a DOM parser instead. Here's how it can be done using PHP's DOMDocument class:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<textarea width="500" >web scripting language of choice.</textarea>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea') as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->nodeValue);
}
```

### Using a regex

If you are absolutely sure that the format of the markup will be consistent, a regex might work, too. To fix your regex, remove the extra spaces from the pattern:

```
preg_match("/[>](.*?)[<]/", $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
string(33) "web scripting language of choice."
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137165)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) instead.

```
var_dump(strip_tags('<textarea width="500" >web scripting language of choice.</textarea>'));
```

Comment: I don't know if `strip_tags` internals use regex though, but this is probably more performatic than `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
<?
$string = '<textarea width="500" >web scripting language of choice.</textarea>';

$match = preg_replace('%<textarea width="500" >(.*?)</textarea>%i', '$1', $string );

echo $match;
//web scripting language of choice.
?>
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for this problem. `strip_tags` will do it just fine.